# Laravel 4 - Rename downloaded files on the fly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a form on my app that allows users to upload a file .. That file gets given a random name, saved to the file system and the details including the original name of the file and the random name of the file gets saved to the database.

When the user clicks the link to re-download the file, i want the file to be renamed to the original file name on the fly but kept as the random name in the file system... if that makes sense.

The code i'm using to download the file at the moment is as follows

```
// Download the document
$file = public_path() . '/uploads/' . $document->userid . '/' . $document->storedname;
return Response::download($file);
```

The random filename that is created on upload is `$document->storedname`

The original name of the file is stored as `$document->originalname`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass it as the second argument to the `download` method:

```
return Response::download($file, $document->originalname);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newName = "download.pdf";
            $filename="samplepdf.pdf";
            $path = storage_path("app/public/" . $filename);
          
            if (!\File::exists($path)) {
                return response()->json(['status' => false], 404);
            }
            
            return response()->download($path,$newName);
```

Comment: Consider adding explanation of your code so that this can be useful for future readers.